# Can't add images to a vscode Extension readme.md

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

## The error

Every time I try to compile the extension with the images inside of the readme.md it returns the following error:

#### > vsce package

```
Executing prepublish script 'npm run vscode:prepublish'...

> waiter@0.0.1 vscode:prepublish D:\projetos\waiter
> npm run package


> waiter@0.0.1 package D:\projetos\waiter
> webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map

    [webpack-cli] Compiler starting...     [webpack-cli] Compiler is using config: 'D:\projetos\waiter\webpack.config.js'
    [webpack-cli] Compiler finished
    asset extension.js 1.18 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
    ./src/extension.ts 2.15 KiB [built] [code generated]
    external "vscode" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    webpack 5.62.2 compiled successfully in 1625 ms
 ERROR  Couldn't detect the repository where this extension is published. The image './readmeImages/initializing.gif' will be broken in README.md. GitHub/GitLab repositories will be automatically detected. Otherwise, please provide the repository URL in package.json or use the --baseContentUrl and --baseImagesUrl options.
```

It recomends me to run with `--baseContentUrl` and `--baseImagesUrl`

#### > vsce package --baseContentUrl --baseImageUrl

```
Executing prepublish script 'npm run vscode:prepublish'...

> waiter@0.0.1 vscode:prepublish D:\projetos\waiter
> npm run package


> waiter@0.0.1 package D:\projetos\waiter
> webpack --mode production --devtool hidden-source-map

    [webpack-cli] Compiler starting... 
    [webpack-cli] Compiler is using config: 'D:\projetos\waiter\webpack.config.js'
    [webpack-cli] Compiler finished
    asset extension.js 1.18 KiB [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
    ./src/extension.ts 2.15 KiB [built] [code generated]
    external "vscode" 42 bytes [built] [code generated]
    webpack 5.62.2 compiled successfully in 1628 ms
 ERROR  Invalid URL: --baseImageUrl/readmeImages/initializing.gif
```

## Readme.md

```
## Features

The gif can show you what I'm talking about, you just open the folder and everything is setup for your development session 

<img src="https://github.com/biel-correa/waiter/tree/master/readmeImages/initializing.gif?raw=true" alt="initializing a project">

## Requirements

The Waiter needs a JSON file so that he knows what you want, but don't worry as soon as it runs he'll ask you to create it.

<img src="https://github.com/biel-correa/waiter/blob/master/readmeImages/askingToCreate.png?raw=true" alt="how it asks to create">
```

[view repository](https://github.com/biel-correa/waiter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to open the github markdown editor so that I could drag and drop the files I wanted to show, when you do like that github generates a custom path for the file.

#### My link

https://github.com/biel-correa/waiter/tree/master/readmeImages/initializing.gif

#### Generated link

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/56176344/143320917-12fe3516-36af-4ec5-a073-5c2dd9abdc46.gif